# Read multiple CSV in different paths and bind them together for each path in R

Tags: r

I have one folder for each subject in my study containing 2-5 csv data which i would like to bind together. For each subject/folder the names of the data are the same.

I want to bind the data for each subject and would like to create a loop. As I have 230 different subjects doing that manually with rbind would be overhelming. The foldername is the subjectID

Any Ideas?

FolderStructure:

```
subject1/day1.csv
subject1/day2.csv
subject1/day3.csv
subject2/day1.csv
subject2/day2.csv
subject3/day1.csv
subject3/day2.csv
subject3/day3.csv
...
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(list_of_files, read.csv))`

Comment: Better than the use of `do.call(rbind, ...)`, depending on the dialect of R you prefer, would be `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(..))` or `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(..), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: If the current directory is the one containing subject1, subject2 and subject3 then `Sys.glob("subject*/*.csv")` will give a character vector containing the paths to all of the files.

Comment: @r2evans the thing is that i want to have in the end one file for subject1 with a binded csv, one file for subject2 with a binded csv and so on. The current directory contains the folders with the subject name and in each subject folder the csv files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll demo using `dplyr::bind_rows`, though it'll work just as well with `data.table::rbindlist`. The base-R variant `do.call(rbind, ...)` does not work as directly since it doesn't have the `.id=`/`idcol=` *easy* option (some elbow-grease can work around this).

```r
list_of_files  ## make this however you want
# [1] "sub1/day1.csv" "sub1/day2.csv" "sub2/day1.csv" "sub2/day2.csv"

alldat <- lapply(setNames(nm=list_of_files), read.csv)
### fake data for demonstration
# alldat <- setNames(replicate(4, mtcars[sample(32,3),], simplify=FALSE), list_of_files)

lapply(split(alldat, sub("/.*", "", names(alldat))), dplyr::bind_rows, .id = "subj")
# $sub1
#                              subj  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Merc 230            sub1/day1.csv 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Lincoln Continental sub1/day1.csv 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# Merc 450SE          sub1/day1.csv 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# Porsche 914-2       sub1/day2.csv 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# Fiat 128            sub1/day2.csv 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Toyota Corona       sub1/day2.csv 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# $sub2
#                              subj  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4           sub2/day1.csv 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Fiat X1-9           sub2/day1.csv 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# Lincoln Continental sub2/day1.csv 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# Merc 240D           sub2/day2.csv 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 450SLC         sub2/day2.csv 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# Hornet 4 Drive      sub2/day2.csv 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

You now have a list, one element per subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem easily by using `read_csv` from `readr` package and by obtaining paths of files in each of `subjectID` folders.

Let's suppose I have three folders `subject1, subject2, subject3` which has csv files with same columns but with different rows.

```r
library(readr)

subjects <- 3

paths <- sort(list.files(recursive = TRUE))

paths
```

```
[1] "subject1/cars1.csv" "subject1/cars2.csv" "subject1/cars3.csv"
[4] "subject2/cars1.csv" "subject2/cars2.csv" "subject3/cars1.csv"
[7] "subject3/cars2.csv" "subject3/cars3.csv"
```

So we can see subject1 folder has 3 csv files, subject2 has 2 csv files and sunject3 folder has 3 csv files. All we need to group these paths to csv files for each subjects folder and give each group of paths to `read_csv`

```r
for (i in seq_len(subjects)) {
    subj <- paste0("subject", i)
    subject_paths <- paths[grepl(subj, paths)]
    file_name <- paste0("subject_", i, "_binded")
    assign(file_name, readr::read_csv(subject_paths, id = "paths"))
}
```

This will create three binded dataframe each for each subject folder.

```r
> subject_1_binded

# A tibble: 15 × 4
   paths                mpg   cyl  disp
   <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 subject1/cars1.csv  27.3     4  79  
 2 subject1/cars1.csv  21       6 160  
 3 subject1/cars1.csv  13.3     8 350  
 4 subject1/cars1.csv  19.2     8 400  
 5 subject1/cars1.csv  10.4     8 460  
 6 subject1/cars2.csv  14.7     8 440  
 7 subject1/cars2.csv  18.7     8 360  
 8 subject1/cars2.csv  30.4     4  95.1
 9 subject1/cars2.csv  15.5     8 318  
10 subject1/cars2.csv  16.4     8 276. 
11 subject1/cars3.csv  21.5     4 120. 
12 subject1/cars3.csv  15.5     8 318  
13 subject1/cars3.csv  19.7     6 145  
14 subject1/cars3.csv  14.3     8 360  
15 subject1/cars3.csv  21.4     4 121  


> subject_2_binded

# A tibble: 15 × 4
   paths                mpg   cyl  disp
   <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 subject2/cars1.csv  27.3     4  79  
 2 subject2/cars1.csv  21       6 160  
 3 subject2/cars1.csv  13.3     8 350  
 4 subject2/cars1.csv  19.2     8 400  
 5 subject2/cars1.csv  10.4     8 460  
 6 subject2/cars2.csv  14.7     8 440  
 7 subject2/cars2.csv  18.7     8 360  
 8 subject2/cars2.csv  30.4     4  95.1
 9 subject2/cars2.csv  15.5     8 318  
10 subject2/cars2.csv  16.4     8 276. 
11 subject2/cars3.csv  21.5     4 120. 
12 subject2/cars3.csv  15.5     8 318  
13 subject2/cars3.csv  19.7     6 145  
14 subject2/cars3.csv  14.3     8 360  
15 subject2/cars3.csv  21.4     4 121  


> subject_3_binded

# A tibble: 15 × 4
   paths                mpg   cyl  disp
   <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 subject3/cars1.csv  27.3     4  79  
 2 subject3/cars1.csv  21       6 160  
 3 subject3/cars1.csv  13.3     8 350  
 4 subject3/cars1.csv  19.2     8 400  
 5 subject3/cars1.csv  10.4     8 460  
 6 subject3/cars2.csv  14.7     8 440  
 7 subject3/cars2.csv  18.7     8 360  
 8 subject3/cars2.csv  30.4     4  95.1
 9 subject3/cars2.csv  15.5     8 318  
10 subject3/cars2.csv  16.4     8 276. 
11 subject3/cars3.csv  21.5     4 120. 
12 subject3/cars3.csv  15.5     8 318  
13 subject3/cars3.csv  19.7     6 145  
14 subject3/cars3.csv  14.3     8 360  
15 subject3/cars3.csv  21.4     4 121
```

So In your case for your 230 subjects you will have 230 binded data.

> Note the use of `assign()` in the last line of for-loop, for your case it would create 230 data.frame (more appropriately, `tbl_df`) object in your global environment.